# Gridle SCSS - 3 responsive columns with fixed heights

Tags: html, css, sass, fixed

I'm trying to make a full page with 3 columns. Only things is they should be fixed on the height. Made the columns with Gridle.

Point is, when I fix one of the columns they all overlap eachother and aren't columns anymore. Any idea how to fix this?

So if I fix the first column the second column is shifting to the left below the first column. I can't simply say "left: 100px" on the 2nd col. As it should stay responsive.

```
.LeftCol {
     @include gridle ( 3 );
     background: #e42e2e;
     color: #fefefe;
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     padding: 0px;
}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparantly, Gridle supports push for columns.

```
@include gridle_push ( 3 );
```

This did the trick.